# Constructor that takes any delegate as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Here's the simplified case. I have a class that stores a delegate that it will call on completion:

```
public class Animation
{
     public delegate void AnimationEnd();
     public event AnimationEnd OnEnd;
}
```

I have another utility class that I want to subscribe to various delegates. On construction I want itself to register to the delegate, but other than that it doesn't care about the type. The thing is, I don't know how to express that in the type system. Here's my pseudo-`C#`

```
public class WaitForDelegate
{
    public delegateFired = false;

    // How to express the generic type here?
    public WaitForDelegate<F that's a delegate>(F trigger)
    {
        trigger += () => { delegateFired = true; };
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks to Alberto Monteiro, I just use `System.Action` as the type for the event. My question now is, how to pass the event to the constructor so it can register itself? This might be a very dumb question.

```
public class Example
{
    Animation animation; // assume initialized

    public void example()
    {
        // Here I can't pass the delegate, and get an error like
        // "The event can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="
        WaitForDelegate waiter = new WaitForDelegate(animation.OnEnd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do what you're asking.

First up, you can't constrain by delegates. The closest code to legal C# is this:

```
public class WaitForDelegate<F> where F : System.Delegate
{
    public bool delegateFired = false;

    public WaitForDelegate(F trigger)
    {
        trigger += () => { delegateFired = true; };
    }
}
```

But it won't compile.

But the bigger problem is that you can't pass delegates around like this anyway.

Consider this simplified class:

```
public class WaitForDelegate
{
    public WaitForDelegate(Action trigger)
    {
        trigger += () => { Console.WriteLine("trigger"); };
    }
}
```

I then try to use it like this:

```
Action bar = () => Console.WriteLine("bar");

var wfd = new WaitForDelegate(bar);

bar();
```

The only output from this is:

```
bar
```

The word `trigger` doesn't appear. This is because delegates are copied by value so that the line `trigger += () => { Console.WriteLine("trigger"); };` is only attaching the handler to `trigger` and not `bar` at all.

The way that you can make all of this work is to stop using events and use Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (NuGet "Rx-Main") which allows you to turn events into LINQ-based `IObservable<T>` instances that can get passed around.

Here's how my example code above would then work:

```
public class WaitForDelegate
{
    public WaitForDelegate(IObservable<Unit> trigger)
    {
        trigger.Subscribe(_ => { Console.WriteLine("trigger"); });
    }
}
```

And you now call it like:

```
Action bar = () => Console.WriteLine("bar");

var wfd = new WaitForDelegate(Observable.FromEvent(h => bar += h, h => bar -= h));

bar();
```

This now produces the output:

```
bar
trigger
```

Notice that the `Observable.FromEvent` call contains the code to attach and detach the handler in a scope that has access to do so. It allows the final subscription call to be unattached with a call to `.Dispose()`.

I've made this class quite simple, but a more complete version would be this:

```
public class WaitForDelegate : IDisposable
{
    private IDisposable _subscription;

    public WaitForDelegate(IObservable<Unit> trigger)
    {
        _subscription = trigger.Subscribe(_ => { Console.WriteLine("trigger"); });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _subscription.Dispose();
    }
}
```

An alternative if you don't want to go for the full use of Rx is to do this:

```
public class WaitForDelegate : IDisposable
{
    private Action _detach;

    public WaitForDelegate(Action<Action> add, Action<Action> remove)
    {
        Action handler = () => Console.WriteLine("trigger");
        _detach = () => remove(handler);
        add(handler);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_detach != null)
        {
            _detach();
            _detach = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
Action bar = () => Console.WriteLine("bar");

var wfd = new WaitForDelegate(h => bar += h, h => bar -= h);

bar();
```

That still does the correct output.

Comment: Oh man. That's brutal. Is there any way to have a class register itself to another class's event without knowing its type? I guess it's impossible because delegates are copied? What about `ref`?

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy - I've added a working solution to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity! Unfortunately I'm wresting with this in Unity, where Rx unfortunately doesn't work. I'm quite surprised events/delegates etc. are such opaque things and not first-class values.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy - Just imagine if they were first-class citizens then any code anywhere could start detaching events. Debugging would be a nightmare. Why doesn't Rx work with Unity?

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy: Delegates **are** first-class values.  But there's no way in vanilla C# to form a reference to a class member.  However, you can pass the event as its constituent `add` and `remove` methods, which is what that `FromEvent` call needs also.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Delegates are first-class, but events are not. That's what I read it as.

Comment: I changed my answer, I still deserves your downvote?

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy - I've added a non-Rx solution. If you can I would still use Rx if I were you though.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy - THis might be of help too: https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx

Answer (score 2):

In .NET there is already a delegate that doesn't receive no parameters, it is the `Action`

So you Animation class could be like that:

```
public class Animation
{
     public event Action OnEnd;
}
```

But you can pass events as parameters, if you try that you will receive this compilation error

> The event can only appear on the left hand side of += or -="

So lets create a interface, and declare the event there

```
public interface IAnimation
{
    event Action OnEnd;
}
```

Using the interface approach you have no external dependencies and you can have many classes that implements that, also is a good practice, depends of abstractions instead concrete types. There is acronym called SOLID that explain 5 principles about better OO code.

And then your animation class implements that

**Obs.:** The **CallEnd** method is just for test purpose

```
public class Animation : IAnimation
{
    public event Action OnEnd;

    public void CallEnd()
    {
        OnEnd();
    }
}
```

And now you WaitForDelegate will receive a **IAnimation**, so the class can handle any class that implements the **IAnimation** class

```
public class WaitForDelegate<T> where T : IAnimation
{
    public WaitForDelegate(T animation)
    {
        animation.OnEnd += () => { Console.WriteLine("trigger"); };
    }
}
```

Then we can test the code that we did with the following code

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new Animation();

        var waitForDelegate = new WaitForDelegate<IAnimation>(a);

        a.CallEnd();
    }
```

The result is

> trigger

Here is the working version on dotnetfiddle

https://dotnetfiddle.net/1mejBL

#### Important tip

If you are working with multithread, you must take some caution to avoid Null Reference Exception

Let's look again the CallEnd method that I've added for test

```
public void CallEnd()
{
    OnEnd();
}
```

OnEnd event could have not value, and then if you try to call it, you will receive Null Reference Exception.

So if you are using C# 5 or lower, do something like this

```
public void CallEnd()
{
    var @event = OnEnd;
    if (@event != null)
        @event();
}
```

With C# 6 it could be like that

```
public void CallEnd()
    => OnEnd?.Invoke();
```

More explanation, you could have this code

```
public void CallEnd()
{
    if (OnEnd != null)
        OnEnd();
}
```

This code that is above, probably make you think that you are safe from Null Reference Exception, but with multithread solution, you aren't. That's because the OnEnd event could be set to null between the execution of `if (OnEnd != null)` and `OnEnd();`

There is a nice article by Jon Skeet about it, you cann see [Clean event handler invocation with C# 6](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I have a question about usage. I'll add to my original question

Comment: That's not what the OP is trying to do. He's trying to know when, as per your answer, `OnEnd` fires.

Comment: @Enigmativity I just changed my answer, my answer still deserve your downvote?

Comment: I've removed the down-vote, but I think your answer still isn't the best. The OP was looking for a general-purpose approach but you've given one that requires knowledge of a specific class/interface. I hope you don't mind my feedback.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks. I respect your opinion, I agree that Eric Lipper/Jon Skeet could provide a better answer than mine, so yes, my answer isn't the best, but is far away to be bad, it is my humble opinion. I would like to say that your approach also require a knowledge about Rx Extensions, that IMHO is hard to get than OO knowledge. To be clear I am not saying that your solution is bad, and deserve a upvote also!

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy did you saw my answer's change?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Thanks. I saw your change, however it assumes `WaitForDelegate` will only ever care about `OnEnd` on the object it accepts.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy you could improve your interface with more events if you need.